# Internal Server Error 500 Why I am Getting This Error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
`` public JsonResult OutBox()
        {
            //int user_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["schoolid"]);
            int user_id = 44;
            var data = db.SMS_Outbox.Where(x => x.schoolid == user_id).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my Action method and Ajax Call It will Return this Error
GET http://localhost:54691/SMS/OutBox/OutBox 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
function LoadOutBox() {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: "../OutBox/OutBox",
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
              alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Go into IIS on your localhost, ensure that your SMS application space has the proper permissions. Also check you virtual directories as well.

Comment: also try changing type: "GET" to type: "POST"

Comment: Does it work if you type `http://localhost:54691/SMS/OutBox/OutBox` in browser?